# iOS crash #memcpy

Tags: ios, nsdata, memcpy

I have some code that sets a UIImage of a UIImageView.

```
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

data is set using

> data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:offsetPointer
>                                   length:offset->size 
>                           freeWhenDone:NO];

and In the debug window I see that data holds data `data =  (NSConcreteData *)  0x06a65c80 59621 bytes`

When I try to assign the image I get this with an lldb hang.

[image]

What is causing this?

Comment: Are you calling retain on the data object? Could you post full code?

Comment: I dont call retain. Only assignment to data is the dataWithBytesNoCopy. I think the image might be corrupt and it crashes.

Comment: Where does `offsetPointer` come from? Is there a possibility its source might be deallocated or freed at some point? You're not copying this data into your NSData instance, so if these bytes are deallocated at some point, it might lead to a crash like this.